# heap space exception during adding a random integer in an ArrayList in an infinite loop?

Tags: java, arraylist, memory-leaks, garbage-collection

```
package com.org;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Random;

public class MemoryProb {

   /**
    * @param args
    */
   public static void main(String[] args) {
       Random random = new Random();

       // Map<Integer, String> sampleMap = new HashMap<Integer, String>();
       ArrayList<Integer> a = new ArrayList<Integer>();

       while (true) {
           // Create and store a random pair.

           int randomValue = random.nextInt();
           System.out.println("ssss   " + randomValue);
           a.add(randomValue);
           System.gc();// i have added this and it delays or it handles the problem 
           // sampleMap.put(randomValue, String.valueOf(randomValue));
       }

   }

}
```

but my concern is I need all the inserted objects in the `ArrayList` , I am not sure whether the `System.gc();` call deletes the initially stored random numbers in the `ArrayList`, Please help and what should be the real fix 
PS: before `System.gc()` was called the program failed in about 7 mins but later after adding it it ran for more than 2 hrs ,but I again I am not sure whether it deletes the initially added numbers in the `ArrayList`.

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

Basically this is being caused by the endless loop.

You are adding and adding to the `ArrayList`

Asking the System to `gc` will not help as the memory is still being used.

There is no way to overcome this.

Comment: but then can I say System.gc() postponed the error? and if it has can you expalin how did it manage to postpone it

Answer (score 0):

I think you misunderstood the usage of `System.gc`. You still have your values added to your list - so you still have got a pointer on that inifite long list.

Think of it that way: Everytime you make a new assignment, the old value goes to your dustbin. `System.gc` ist just cleaning up that dustbin.
In your case, there is nothing in your dustbin, because you never assign a new value - you just create a new one, that you pile up on your desk.

Hope I could give you an idea why this isn't a memory problem.

EDIT: `System.gc` does NOT delete any values you have stored in your array! So you have an infinite amount of variables, that are never deleted.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly system.gc() is not a committing command, it is just a triggering command which will generate a thread to check whether garbage collection is required or not and if it is required then it will clear the heap size only for the objects that are not in use.

Secondly garbage collection can't be done on any element which is not initialized by null and hence if your program is able to run more than 7 minutes after using system.gc() then it is definitely some other memory location which is deallocated but for sure your code will produce outofmemory exception when your heap size get full and garbage collection can't be done.

Answer (score 0):

`System.gc()` does not change your program in any way as the JVM will perform garbage collection anyway. It is guaranteed, that before an `OutOfMemoryError` is thrown, all possible attempts for freeing unused objects are made.

But calling `System.gc()` more often might simply make your program *slower* that’s why it may look like the error appears later but the program still does exactly the same thing as before; it only requires more time for that.